# How many 5 digit numbers with at least two digits prime and two digits square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations

> How many 5 digit numbers with at least two digits prime and at least two digits square?

All digits are different and non-zero.

So I have seen this problem online and can’t find a solution so just wondering (i) if I’m correct and (ii) if there are any other ways out there.

My solution:

At least two digits prime and two digits square means that at most one digit has neither of these properties (N). We have 3 square (S) numbers and 4 prime numbers (P) in the range also.

Hence the cases are

NSSPP -> $2 \times 3 \times 2 \times 4 \times 3 =144$

SSSPP -> $3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 4 \times 3 =72$

SSPPP -> $3 \times 2 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 =144$

Total = $360$

How’s my solution looking?

If it’s wrong why? If correct, are there any other methods

Edit: changes 6 to 2 in the first line as only neither digits are 6 and 8

Comment: How many possible "neither" digits are there? You seem to think there are six from how I understand your first product.

Comment: Oh yes that bit is wrong, I was calculating that with N being free to be anything

Comment: You are only counting numbers in which square digits precede prime digits (and a "neither" digit, if there is one, comes first).

Comment: @BarryCipra multiply everything by 5?

Comment: It's not quite that simple.

Comment: @BarryCipra I’m not quite sure because if you want to know how to rearrange 10 numbers it’s just 10!, you don’t have to times bu anything in case you have 9 in front of 7 or 7 in front of 9?

Comment: After you've place a "neither" digit in one of $5$ positions, you still need to choose $2$ of the remaining $4$ positions for the square digits, so there's also a factor of $4\choose2$.

Comment: The number $11226$ has or has not two of the digits square ($1=1^2$) abd two of the digits prime ($2$ is a prime)? In other words, is it allowed to have repeated squares and/or primes among the digits? This is because the counting of the NSSPP cases uses for the SS pair the number of possibilities $3\times 2$, and for the PP pair $4\times 3$, thus suggesting that no repetition is allowed.

Comment: @dan_fulea yes no repetition is allowed, does that change the answer from what the accepted answer is?

Comment: We still do not have a clear statement. (But have an accepted answer...) To be well understood, i will take examples. The number $11226$ has five digits, namely $1,1,2,2,6$. Among these digits, two of them are squares, the first two digits (taken from left to right), and two of them are primes, the next two. This five digit number is not counted. Moreover. The accepted answer counts in the case $SSSPP$  $1\times 6$ possibilities before we permute. This allows only $149PP$, then we scramble. But why is $114PP$ excluded (or not counted elsewhere)? Please *first* give a clear statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observe we have three cases:

> **SSPPN**: In order to count this typo we do the following:
>
> - Choose $2$ digits square from the set of digits square: you can do this in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways.
> - Choose $2$ digits prime from the set of digits prime: you can do this in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.
> - Choose $1$ digits neither from the set of digits neither: you can do this in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways.
> - Since the digits are all different, you can permute them as you want: so you have $5!$ ways to permute.
>
> So for this case you have:
>   \begin{equation}
> \binom{3}{2}\cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{2}{1} \cdot 5! = 4320
> \end{equation}

And

> **SSSPP**: You have:
>
> - $3$ digits square from the set of digits square: you can do this in $\binom{3}{3}$ ways.
> - $2$ digits prime from the set of digits prime: you can do this in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.
> - Since the digits are all different, you can permute them as you want: so you have $5!$ ways to permute.
>
> So for this case you have:
>   \begin{equation}
> \binom{3}{3}\cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 5! = 720
> \end{equation}

And

> **SSPPP**: In order to count this typo we do the following:
>
> - $2$ digits square from the set of digits square: you can do this in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways.
> - $3$ digits prime from the set of digits prime: you can do this in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways.
> - Since the digits are all different, you can permute them as you want: so you have $5!$ ways to permute.
>
> So for this case you have:
>   \begin{equation}
> \binom{3}{2}\cdot \binom{4}{3} \cdot 5! = 1440
> \end{equation}

So the result is $4320+720+1440=6480$.